# Probability that two persons are in the same point at the same time

Tags: probability

I am trying to figure out a real life probability problem. I am no mathematician, but I am an engineer, so I should be able to formulate the problem correctly.

I have been head banging the wall to solve this for few days and I am stuck -

- The time space is 365 days.
- A moves from one Point to another **N** times.
- B moves from one Point to another **M** times.
- There are **P** Points.
- A and B don't have to move at the same time but they may
- A and B don't know about each other
- They can move to any point
- Their choices are independent (They don't influence each others)
- One move is instant.
- At T=0, A and B are on separate point.
  Thanks

What is the probability that A & B are on the same Point at least one time?
Is it solvable at all ?

**EDIT 1**
Thanks to @N.Bach answer, I add the following missing informations :

- $N$ and $M$ are not random variables
- Assuming $T_a$ and $T_b$ are the time A and B stay on a Point P, these are integer
- All Points are equally probable

**EDIT 2**

Thanks so much to both of you.

I think we all have a different view of what the real life problem could be, as we would all try to assume A is us.

as an example, 
You and your childhood mate you haven't seen in 10 years, both go on holidays for 2 weeks, leaving on the same date. What is the probability you both visit the same place at the same time?

Another case scenario, you go in holidays, and you land in the same city as an old colleague you haven't seen for ages, who has been living there for few years.

Taking a number of cities of 1000, the probability this happens, according to @NickG's answer, is around 0.01%.

Multiplying this result by the probability of you meeting him randomly in person while you both in the same city, makes the final odds very low.
Of course, there are few cities around with less than a thousand people, but there are so many of them.

I got interested by this question because this happened to few people I met, (including myself), and I definitely haven't got this conversation with  more than 100 person. (now that is online, this number drastically increased..)

An hypothesis would be that there is an hidden parameter that escapes our logic, which would explain why on earth it happened to me twice, and I met 3 person which had the same experience, and I am definitely not walking the street asking who else had this experience...

A realistic answer would be that the odds this happens often to a group of people, which I am part of, is statistically possible.

Comment: Somewhat like a random walk.  Might be worth looking at those.

Comment: During a move, can they move to any of the points? Also, if one move takes one day, and $A$ moves $N$ times and $B$ moves $M$ tones, and that's it, what does $365$ have to do with anything?

Comment: @Arthur Sorry I just updated the question.
One move is instant, 
They can move to any points.
For example A moves 3 times in 365 days, therefore can stay in 4 points for a period of time T1 + T2 + T3 + t4 = 365 days

Comment: I see that you have edited the question but you don't seem to have answered Arthur's question.  Can they move to any point in one step?  It seems that they can opt to stay still.  They don't have to move at the same time but may they?  Do they have knowledge of each other's moves?  Are their choices independent?  Are they trying to meet or avoid each other?  It would seem that you could fix one of them with no effect.

Comment: @badjohn Yes they can move to any point in one step, they may move at the same time, don't have knowledge of each other's move, independent choices that don't affect each other's move.

Comment: "Of course N < 365 and M < 365 and P > (N + M)" - These sound like nontrivial and nonobvious conditions to me. Most people move more than once per day, and may well visit the same places many times each year. So I would have guessed N >> 365 (and a nonuniform distribution on the state space when moving around).

Comment: @badjohn
I just had an idea, would it simply be MAX(N,M)/(P-1) ?

Comment: @TMM For real world application, I was thinking that P is a city in the world, and plane tickets are expensive. I was thinking to multiply this probability by the probability that you meet B  in a city assuming both are in the same city.

Comment: I thought "same place" meant that people would run into each other. If P represents a set of cities, then clearly being in the "same place" means something else. And that still leaves the issue that a uniform distribution on places to move to is not very realistic. I would assume both persons had a "home town" which they'll be likely to visit after almost each trip, and some places are more often visited than others.

Comment: @TMM Sorry there was missing bits, The Real World scenario is that A&B know each other from school, one person changes home town and moves permanently abroad, time passes, they loose contact.
The probability they land in the same city the same day in a year.

Comment: Is time measured continuously and moves can occur at any time, or is time measured in discrete intervals with moves only occurring on those intervals? Can a person move more than once in a day?

Comment: @TMM I updated the question with an accurate description of the real life example I was referring to.

Comment: People you know/get along with probably have some common interests with you. Even without being in contact, the odds you visit similar places is higher compared to someone completely unrelated. There's also the vacation effect, there are dates at which people are more likely to travel, which increases the odds again. The hidden parameter would be culture, interest, upbringing, etc, basically the probability of when and where you travel. You can probably model that with Markov chains.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### EDIT 2

After thinking for a while, it seems to me that part of the problem you're actually struggling with is how to state and specify the "real life" problem
that you want to solve, rather than actually solving it. One way to state and solve the problem is addressed below, here I'd like to discuss about other ways to specify the problem.

In short, you may want to have a look at Markov chains, or even hidden Markov chains.
One way to see Markov chains, is that you have a system that can evolve between certain states, with a certain probability. Here for example, person $A$ could be your system, and its state could be which city $A$ is currently in. You can make things non uniform by specifying the probabilities with which the system can transition from one state to another.
Want to include $B$? Make the system pairs of cities. Don't want to make the decision of $A$ and $B$ independent? That's already built-in with the probability to transition from one state to another. Want to have time play a role? One transition can be equivalent to one time unit, and a state can transition into itself to simulate that $A$ and $B$ do not move.
Want to simulate a 2-day vacation to another city (staying 2 days somewhere, coming back to hometown)? Make a special state that can only transition back to the state it came from...

I think you get the idea. To conclude, the approach below could be modeled by a Markov chain, but it would probably be very annoying. The more "natural" thing to do with Markov chain would be to have $N$ and $M$ as random variables, enforcing them to be constant would probably be annoying?
(Not sure, I haven't done any Markov chain in ages.)

### Original answer

You need to specify in some way what the probabilities are when $A$ and $B$ move around...
For instance for $A$, is $N$ fixed or a random variable?
Assuming $N$ is fixed, $A$ will visit $N+1$ points, let $T_i$ be the number of days $A$ stay at the $i$-th point.
Can the $i$-th point and the $(i+1)$-th point be the same? I'll assume that they must be distinct.
I'll also assume that $T_i\ge 1$ for every $i$, and that every $T_i$ is an integer.

Just looking at the $T_i$, there is $364\choose N$ possible choices of them.
This corresponds to all the ways $A$ can choose to move around, without specifying where.

When looking at the locations, $A$ can choose between $P-1$ destinations, so if we disregard the "when", we have a choice between $(P-1)^N$ trajectories. I ignored the starting point, but if this is also a variable make that $(P-1)^{N+1}$.

If you put those together, there are ${364\choose N}(P-1)^N$ ways for $A$ to move around in the span of one year. Are all of these ways equally probable? Or is there some specific process for $A$ to choose when and where he moves?
Unless you specify this information, it will be difficult to solve your problem.

Ps: if $A$ and $B$ start on the same point, they will obviously be together on the same point on day 1... you may want to revise your problem statement.

### EDIT 1

Nick G was faster than me, but I want to add a few remarks to his approach
(read his answer first).

When $A$ and $B$ move simultaneously, there are indeed $(p-1)^2$ possible pairs of destination, but only $p-2$ outcomes where $A$ and $B$ meet. Indeed $A$ can move to $p-1$ points, but that number includes the point where $B$ is currently at. Because they cannot meet there, only $p-2$ cities (and outcomes) remain.
So the probability that they do not meet right after they both move is
$$\frac{(p-1)^2-(p-2)}{(p-1)^2}$$
When $X=k$, the probability they do not meet during the course of one year then becomes
$$
P(\text{$A$ and $B$ do not meet}\mid X=k)=
\left(\frac{p-2}{p-1}\right)^{N+M-2X}\times \left(\frac{(p-1)^2-(p-2)}{(p-1)^2}\right)^X
$$

The last remaining problem is how to determine $X$.
Let $T^A_i$ be the number of days $A$ stays in the $i$-th city he visits, likewise for $T^B_i$. Given the values of $T^A_i$ and $T^B_i$ it is possible to compute $X$. You didn't provide any information on the probability of having one set of $T^A_i$, $T^B_i$ over another, so I'll just assume uniform distribution. Also dealing with the durations of the stay is annoying, so instead let $U^A_i$ be the night when $A$ travels from the $i$-th city to the $(i+1)$-th city.
The sequence $(U^A_i)_{1\le i\le N}$ is strictly increasing and has integer values between $1$ and $364$ (inclusive).
We have likewise a sequence $(U^B_i)_{1\le i\le M}$ for $B$.

Without loss of generality assume $N\le M$. For an integer $k$, $0\le k\le N$,
we want to compute
$P(X=k)$,
the probability that $X$ is equal to $k$. Because we assume uniform distribution, it is the number of ways to draw both
$(U^A_i)$ and $(U^B_i)$ such that they share exactly $k$ identical night values divided by the total number of ways to draw
$(U^A_i)$ and $(U^B_i)$.
There are $364\choose k$ ways to choose $k$ distinct nights on which $A$ and $B$ both move. Following this, $A$ still move $N-k$ times on the remaining $364-k$ nights, while $B$ move $M-k$ times. However, those
$(N-k)+(M-k)$ nights must be distinct, there are
$364-k\choose N+M-2k$ ways to chose the nights they move on, and
${N+M-2k\choose N-k} = {N+M-2k\choose M-k}$ ways to decide whether $A$ or $B$ is the one moving during those nights.

In the end there are
$$
{364\choose k}\times{364-k\choose N+M-2k}\times{N+M-2k\choose N-k}
=\frac{364!}{k!\,(364-N-M+k)!\,(N-k)!\,(M-k)!}
$$
different ways to draw the nights $(U^A_i)$ and $(U_i^B)$ so that $A$ and $B$ move the same night exactly $k$ times.
In total, there are ${364\choose N}\times{364\choose M}$ ways to draw the nights (without constraints). This means we can compute 
$P(X=k)$.

To conclude,
$$
P(\text{$A$ and $B$ do not meet})
=\sum_{k=0}^N P(X=k)\times P(\text{$A$ and $B$ do not meet}\mid X=k)
$$
and you want to take $1$ minus the above to answer your problem.
I have no clue whether there is a nice simplification of the various formula, but at least a computer can do the work for you.

Also note that the assumption in this model are not very "realistic".
As TMM pointed out, most people should have some kind of pattern when travelling. Uniform distribution on the $(U^A_i)$ and $(U^B_i)$ also means
the below situations have the same likelihood:

- $A$ visits one city per day $N$ days in a row then do not move the rest of the year
- $A$ stays $365/(N+1)$ days in each city he visits
- anything in between
- and let's not forget it's the same for $B$
- the model also assumes that $(U^A_i)$ and $(U^B_i)$ are independant by the way

Depending on the circumstances, those may not be desirable properties...

Comment: All your points and suggestions are valid. Originally, I though that all the ways for A & B to move around in the span of one year should be equally probable, but now you mention it... I think they should not be equally probable.  I will update this question accordingly to your suggestions.

Comment: I updated the question saying the ways for A & B to move around the span of one year were equally probable, simply because I don't know how to formulate the fact they are not...

Comment: @Cooluhuru read your edit, you specified how $A$ and $B$ decide **where** they move, but not **when**. I assumed a uniform distribution and included a possible answer (partial, see Nick G) in my edit.

Comment: this is (to my point of view) a god-like answer. I'd really like to mark @Nick G answer as correct as well, but unfortunately I cannot mark both as correct.

Comment: Also, I updated the question with a more acute description of the real life scenario I had in mind.

Answer (score 2):

The length of time involved is irrelevant.

Whenever a person moves, whether it is $A$ or $B$, either they move to the point where the other person is or they don't. The probability they don't move to the other person's point on any one move is $\frac {p-2}{p-1}$, and this applies to $M+N$ moves.

Hence the probability that $A$ and $B$ meet at least once is $$1-\left(\frac {p-2}{p-1}\right)^{M+N}$$

> There were different interpretations of how to measure time. What's above holds if time is measured continuously and the probability of simultaneous moves is zero. What's below isn't correct - see the comments - but I'll leave it here because edits and comments by the OP and N.Bach refer to it. N.Bach's answer contains a better analysis of simultaneous moves.

However, there is a complication when moves occur simultaneously.

***Assumption***: when $A$ and $B$ move simultaneously they only meet if they both move to the same point. Moving to the point that the other person leaves does not count as meeting.

In this case there are $(p-1)^2$ pairs of destination points and $p-1$ outcomes where $A$ and $B$ meet. (Analogy: you roll two dice; you meet when you roll a double.) In effect, simultaneous moves have the same outcome probabilities as a move by one person.

Let $X$ be the number of times $A$ and $B$ move simultaneuosly. Then the overall probability that $A$ and $B$ meet at least once becomes $$1-\left(\frac {p-2}{p-1}\right)^{M+N-X}$$

Comment: This is a very good observation.  It makes the problem much simpler.

Comment: There are p-2 outcomes where $A$ and $B$ meet, so you need to tweak the probability a little bit...
Also, the length of time is actually relevant in determining the value of X.

Comment: Yes, you are right. By my definition, both the points that $A$ and $B$ occupy are excluded, hence $p-2$ outcomes. On the other hand, if time is measured continuously, I could argue that the probability of simultaneous moves is zero. If time is measured in discrete intervals, then I agree I need to account for that too when considering simultaneous moves. I'm about to read your edited answer...